# Problem with display of Lao text in Java Swing Components

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jlabel

I am trying to display Lao language text:

ຄິ້ງເຄັງສາຍພານ

in a `JLabel` in Java swing using sample code obtained from the [following link](https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=d91fbb89-359a-4eda-9064-4f060fae286c#gsc.tab=0).

The font picked is DokChampa. However, the text displayed is:

[image: Sample screen-shot]

Note that the characters above the alphabets are displaced and moved to the right. However, the same text entered in Notepad or other editors in the system using the DokChampa font are displayed correctly.

When data entry is done in the `JTextField` using the Windows supported Lao keyboard also, the behavior is the same.

Other Fonts tried like LaoUI also have the same behavior in Java Swing components

Using JDK 1.8.0_152. My sample program is as below. Expected output is to see the text displayed as mentioned above.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestLaos {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JLabel l = new JLabel();
            String [] lstr = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment ().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
            Font [] fList = new Font [lstr.length];
            for (int i = 0; i <lstr.length; i ++)
            {
             fList [i] = new Font (lstr [i], Font.PLAIN, 20);
            }
            String rawString = new String("ຄິ້ງເຄັງສາຍພານ");
            l.setText(rawString);
            Font f = l.getFont ();
            if (f.canDisplayUpTo (rawString)!=-1)
            {//Find fonts that can not be displayed, then find available fonts
                for (int i = 0; i <fList.length; i ++)
                {
                    if (fList [i] .canDisplayUpTo (rawString) ==-1 && fList [i].getFontName().startsWith("DokChampa"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Using font " + fList [i].getFontName() + " to display " + rawString);
                        l.setFont (fList [i]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
           
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, l);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Also what JDK version are you using?

Comment: JDK version is 1.8.0_152

Comment: Nice one for adding the MRE! OTOH a) not all PCs will have DokChampa font installed, and.. b) The code shows the same (actually [even worse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbwXf.png)) behavior here using Arial Unicode MS.

Comment: Using 1.8.0_261, I get a similarly shifted [image](https://i.imgur.com/0gqDGQM.png); similar result with JavaFX; nothing on `stdout`; Lucida Grande font is Swing default; NetBeans 8.2 editor displays shifted, but BBEdit displays correctly.

Comment: @trashgod It seems a variety of JREs (with either Swing or Java-FX) with a number of different fonts will not display Lao glyphs correctly. :( I'm guessing the problem lies with Java, not the fonts.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Windows 10 operating system.  I'm using an Oracle Java JDK 14.0.2 and compiling to a Java 8 standard.

Here are the results of my test.

[image: Laos Fonts]

Some of the text is correct and some isn't.  I suspect problems with the fonts.

Here's the code I ran.  Try it on your system and see what happens.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestLaos implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TestLaos());
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Laos Fonts");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        String rawString = new String("ຄິ້ງເຄັງສາຍພານ");
        List<Font> laosFonts = getLaosFonts(rawString);
        frame.add(createMainPanel(laosFonts, rawString), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel(List<Font> laosFonts, String rawString) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2, 10, 10));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        
        for (Font font : laosFonts) {
            JLabel label1 = new JLabel(font.getFontName());
            label1.setFont(label1.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 20f));
            panel.add(label1);
            
            JLabel label2 = new JLabel(rawString);
            label2.setFont(font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 20f));
            panel.add(label2);
        }
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private List<Font> getLaosFonts(String rawString) {
        List<Font> laosFonts = new ArrayList<>();
        Font[] list = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts();
        
        for (Font font : list) {
            if (font.canDisplayUpTo(rawString) == -1) {
                laosFonts.add(font);
            }
        }
        
        return laosFonts;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I get [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KqobL3KW2wTh7XAi5ILWiIa-4hcakobV/view?usp=sharing) this when I run your code. However, the Noto fonts DO NOT display non-Lao text (Eg: ງ່າມປູ ເຂົ້າເລກ 1 ແລະ ເລກຖອຍ 33081/86 , 3309-1702026) that contains numeric data also.

Moreover, I have the DejaVu fonts installed on my system. Any specific reason that they would NOT be picked up?

Comment: @Saumya: The code I posted should retrieve all fonts registered to the local graphics environment.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, that led me to look into this thread on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264642/how-to-force-win10-to-install-fonts-in-c-windows-fonts 
The DejaVu font was installed for the current user. When I installed that for all users, the code picked up DejaVu font & displayed the Lao text correctly.